# Two meanings of the verb "apprendre"

Tags: verbes, passé-composé

In the past tense, "apprendre" goes like this :

> J'ai appris à lire

for "*I learned to read*"

But what if you want to use it in the other meaning? Want I mean is that, verbally, you can say

> J'ai [appris] à Sarah à lire

As in "*I taught Sarah to read*"

How should we write the verb here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no different way to write it, you can use:

> *J'ai appris à lire à Sarah*

or, to avoid two consecutive *à xx*:

> *Sarah, je lui ai appris à lire*

It is not incorrect but *j'ai appris à Sarah à lire* sounds less common, probably because it breaks the compound *apprendre à lire*.

Comment: It is quite common actually, but more like "Je lui ai appris à lire". Though, you can hear it sometimes in the form I used in my example

Comment: A quick search leads to believe that *je lui ai appris à lire* is the most common, then *j'ai appris à lire à xx*, and finally *j'ai appris à xx à lire*.

Comment: @jlliagre « J'ai appris à lire à Sarah » et « Sarah, je lui ai appris à lire » ne sont pas des équivalents; la différence est ténue, certes, mais les deux assertions correspondent à des contextes sous jacents qui ne sont pas exactement semblables.

Comment: @user168676 Pas significativement différents non plus... Dans les deux cas, on a bien transmis à Sarah une compétence, ce qui est l'objet de la question.

Comment: @ jiliagre Prenons un premier exemple:

« Qu'est- que vous savez de Sarah? Sarah, je lui ai appris à lire; cela ne m'a pas permis d'apprendre quoi que ce soit sur Sarah, sauf un peu de sa façon d'étudier. »
 
Cela insinue que la seule interaction avec Sarah de la personne qui répond a été sur le plan d'une relation de tuteur à élève. Si au lieu de cela on a « J'ai appris à lire à Sarah. » on est confronté à un début de narration qui ne présage de rien en particulier. Êtes-vous d'accord?

Comment: @user168676 On peut en effet broder toutes sortes d'interprétations autour de ces phrases. Peu importe, l'essentiel est que Sarah sache lire... :-) *I taught Sarah to read* --- *Sarah, I taught her to read*

Answer (score 1):

The word "apprendre" means also to acquire a habit, for example, "il connaît les règles, mais il refuse d'apprendre à les suivre", it doesn't mean that he doesn't know rules.